# go install apache arrow

Tags: go, apache-arrow

I'm a beginning go user trying to install the go apache arrow module, so I can run the introductory examples in the [user guide](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/apache/arrow/go/arrow). When I try to install the library, I receive the following errors:

```
$ go install github.com/apache/arrow/go@latest
go: github.com/apache/arrow/go@latest: 
module github.com/apache/arrow@latest found (v0.0.0-20220326002331-5bd4d8ec279d), 
but does not contain package github.com/apache/arrow/go

$ go install github.com/apache/arrow/go@v7.0.0
go: github.com/apache/arrow/go@v7.0.0: github.com/apache/arrow/go@v7.0.0: 
invalid version: go/go.mod has post-v7 module path
"github.com/apache/arrow/go/v7" at revision go/v7.0.0
```

I've been able to install other go packages successfully, so I don't understand why this install is erroring out.

What is the correct invocation of "go install" to install apache arrow?

Comment: You should use the /v7

Comment: your imports must use "github.com/apache/arrow/go/v7"

Comment: Edited my question; the trouble is I don't have the right invocation of "go install" - any help in that aspect is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way: assume you have done `go mod init` in your local project, you can start to write a file and import `github.com/apache/arrow/go/v8` Like this example:

https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/go/arrow/_examples/helloworld/main.go

Now you can easily do

`go mod tidy && go mod vendor`

And the tool should recognize the imports to download and vendorize.

Or you can do explicitly in your project dir,

`go get -u github.com/apache/arrow/go/v8`

then run the mod tidy and mod vendor

Comment: I use `go mod tidy` to install all dependencies.  I practically never run `go install`

Comment: Exactly what I needed as a newbie -- this functionality wasn't obvious to me. Awesome. Thank you !

Comment: go install is useful to install binaries such as golangci-lint. If you need a library you want to do `go get`